# Haskell - Parse error on input '->'

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I created this program to return a list of positions of a matrix that no has  zero value.

**This Code:**

```
type Pos = (Int,Int)
type Matrix = [[Int]]

v0 [Pos]->Matrix->[Pos]
v0 [] m =[]
v0 [p:ps] m = if ((takeH m p) == 0) then v0 ps m
                                    else p:v0 ps m

takeH:: Matrix->Pos->Int
takeH m (i,j)= (m!!(i-1))!!(j-1)
```

**Produces this error:**

```
Parse error on input '->'
Failed,modules loades: nome.
```

**Why ?**

I hope that I've been clear.

Comment: Did you forget `::` in `v0 [Pos]->Matrix->[Pos]` ? 

`v0 :: [Pos]->Matrix->[Pos]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `::` before the type of a function.

```
-- vv here
v0 :: [Pos] -> Matrix -> [Pos]
v0 [] _ = []
-- v    v also parenthesis, not square brackets
v0 (p:ps) m = if ((takeH m p) == 0) then v0 ps
                                    else p:v0 ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your takeH function needs to take a Matrix and a Pos as arguments, but you only seem to pass it a Pos...? I assume you want something like `takeH x (i, j) = (x!!(i-1))!!(j-1)`.

In general, I highly warn against using partial functions such as !!. What if your Matrix doesn't contain enough values, and goes out of bounds? Your program will terminate and throw an error. Take that into consideration as well